# Whats the idea behind the slash on preg_match?

Tags: php, preg-match

Why I can't write this ?

```
if ( preg_match( 'My' , 'My name is David !' ) ) {}
```

And this is proper :

```
if ( preg_match( '/My/' , 'My name is David !' ) ) {}
```

What's the idea behind the `/` ?!

Comment: Relevant docs: http://us.php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.delimiters.php

Comment: MLeFevre has the answer. Note that regex functions in languages that don't use delimiters have always a separate param where you can put global modifiers.

Answer (score 1):

Delimiters are there to identify the start of modifier flags.

For example the `i` flag:

`i (PCRE_CASELESS)
If this modifier is set, letters in the pattern match both upper and lower case letters.`

So with delimiters, you could do

```
if  preg_match('/my/i', 'My name is David !'))
```

and not have to worry about case. Without delimiters, you would be unable to distinguish between what you're actually searching for, and any flags you also wanted to use in conjunction with your search. Here are some [Other Modifiers](http://php.net/manual/en/reference.pcre.pattern.modifiers.php).

Comment: However it is possible to use inline modifiers inside the pattern itself: `/(?i)my/`